# substring from string

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

```
-(void)ClkRandomBtn:(id)sender
{

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString:@"http://chinesepokerwithfriends.com/chinesepoker/rand_user.php?"]]; //POST set up. 
    NSMutableString *postBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
    [req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [req setHTTPBody:[postBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    returnString= [returnString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"withString:@"" ];   
    NSLog(@"returnString=%@",returnString);


    randomplayer=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [randomplayer addObject:[returnString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]];


    NSMutableArray *Pinfo=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i=0; i<[randomplayer count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[randomplayer objectAtIndex:i]);

        NSString *strplayerinfo=[[NSString alloc]init];

        strplayerinfo=[randomplayer objectAtIndex:i];

        [Pinfo addObject:[strplayerinfo componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<[Pinfo count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@" second array%@",[Pinfo objectAtIndex:i]);
    } 
}
```

This is the my code to get the string in `dheeru 9411279057 dheeru@gmail.com/abc 9876543215 abc@gmail.com/` I want to split each of it into single string but this code is not working. How to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
[randomplayer addObject:[returnString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]];
```

with

```
[randomplayer addObjectsFromArray:[returnString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]];
```

for a quick fix.

---

You can probably replace the closing snippet of your method with the snippet below –

```
NSString * trimmedString = [returnString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet  characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/"];
NSArray * chunks = [trimmedString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

NSMutableArray *Pinfo=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < [chunks count]; i++)
{
    NSString * playerInfo = [chunks objectAtIndex:i];

    [Pinfo addObject:[playerInfo componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
}

for (int i = 0; i < [Pinfo count]; i++)
{
    NSArray * info = [Pinfo objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"Player %d", i);
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", [info objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSLog(@"Phone: %@", [info objectAtIndex:1]);
    NSLog(@"Email: %@", [info objectAtIndex:2]);
}
```